# linux script to dump web page from a browser to image file

Tags: linux, image, browser, screenshot

Fo you know any script to make a screenshot of rendered web browser contents to an image file?

For now I've tried:

- wkhtmltoimage - doesnt dump flash
- cutycapt - problems to compile on my hosting
- khtml2png - problems with compilation

At home I'm using Ubuntu, hosting is on Debian

Comment: Is it just me, or do you have unreasonable requirements regarding Flash?

Answer (score 1):

Never got around to trying myself, but check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb. You should be able to run Firefox in xvfb and just save an image of the whole virtual window.

Answer (score 0):

The `xwd(1)` program can capture a running browser window's contents and save it to a file or stdout:

```
xwd -out /tmp/image.out
```

You can view it again with `xwud(1)`.

The ImageMagick `import(1)` command can also capture X11 windows or any rectangular portion of the screen. It also supports many output file formats, which might be nicer than the standard `xwd` format.

Answer (score 0):

- PDFMyURL - really useful except bug with header sending. They have
  simple "API". Unless you need simple grab the screen from WebKit, it
  is best solution IMHO
- If you have own VDS, I recommend to discover [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)  See rasterize.js

UPD: I have just seen this is necropost Z)